# Share my objects using a link - ionic3

Tags: ionic-framework, share, socialshare

I'm imagining this situation: I have my app opened on my device. I've just created a new element (object) in my app, for example a new Film like this

```
film = {
    title: 'Shark 3',
    subtitle: 'the revenge',
    date: '12-11-2019',
    plot: '...'
};
```

and I've saved it in my local storage. Now I want to share it on socials (WhatsApp, Facebook...) generating a link to this object. By clicking on this link I want my app (or the app store if it is not installed) to open. In case my app is installed, it should display a page with the film's information.
Is it possible? How to do this in ionic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you want to present is stored within the app and so available on every device your app is installed, I guess? Or is it data loaded from a backend?

What you want to do is called a Deep Link. This means clicking on a links opens your app and redirects the user to a specific page depending on the link.

This is possible with Ionic and the [DeepLink native plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/deeplinks/).

But there need to be done other things outside your app to make it work. You need to register and verify your domain with Google and/or Apple.

And be aware testing this is very uncomfortable. It will only work with signed packes. So just running `ionic cordova run android` won't work, you will have to go the whole way creating a signed package as you need to do when you're going to publish it.

Here is a [Blog article](https://blog.ionicframework.com/deeplinking-in-ionic-apps/) describing the functionality.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I read the blog but there is a thing I didn't understand. The data I want to share is saved in my storage app, using cordova-sqlite-storage and saving it with `storage.set('my_film', this.film)` for example. How to send this data through a simple link? I understood what deeplinking is, but it is not useful because the data isn't known by the person who clicks on the link. Did you get the situation?

Comment: Do I get you right? One of your users creates such an film entry in the app which is stored in the local storage, and then you want to share that data with another user on another device? And on this other device then the data should be stored in the local storage? First, as I wrote, you need to register an custom URL scheme as described in the Ionic blog post. This is necessary to open the App if clicked on a link. To transport the data, you could serialize the film object and attach it to the link, and the with the deep link stuff unserialize it and store it on the other device